# Returning a json object in select - causes slow down

Tags: sql, subquery, sql-server-2016

In the stored procedure, I'm using `CTE` table to return a data set as `JSON`. As the amount of data increased, I have noticed that one particular part of the stored procedure is causing the slowdown after running the execution plan.

There're 4 tables and they are linked using `ID`. For simplicity, I'm going to refer to them as `Table1, Table2, Table3 and Table4`.

```
Table1 
(
    Id (int primary key), 
    Colum1,
    Colum2,
    ---
)

Table2
(
    Id (int primary Key)
    Table1Id (foreign key) --To table 1 Id,(non-unique, non-clustered) index
    Colum1,
    Colum2,
    ---
)

Table3
(
    Id (int primary key),
    Table2Id (foreign key) -- To table 2 Id, has (non-unique, non-clustered) index
    Table4id (foreign key) -- To table 4 id, has (non-unique, non-clustered) index
    Colum1,
    Colum2,
    ---
)

Table4
(
    Id (int primary key),
    Colum1,
    Colum2,
    --
)
```

Table1 has roughly `55000` records and Table2 has `75000` records. I'm passing a `JSON` filter to the stored procedure to do some filtering and my final output gets return as a `JSON` object. However, not the filter nor the returning as json is causing slowdown. In my `SELECT` statement, I'm building an object within using subquery. That's what is causing the issue.

Here's is the query:

```
(
 SELECT

      Colum1,
      Colum2,
      Colum3,
      ...
      --Causes Slowness
      Object1 = (
                       SELECT t2.Id,
                              t2.Table1Id,
                              t2.Colum1,
                              t2.Colum2,
                              ...
                              -- Causes Slowness
                              Object2 = (
                                  SELECT t3.Id,
                                         t3.Table2id,
                                         t3.Table3Id,
                                         t4.Colum1 + ' ' + t4.Colum2 as newcolumn,
                                         ...
                                  FROM Table3 t3
                                  INNER JOIN Table4 t4
                                      ON t3.Table4Id = t4.Id
                                  WHERE t2.Id = t3.Table2Id
                                  ORDER BY CASE WHEN @OrderByAndOrder = 'colum1 asc' THEN u.Colum1 END ASC,
                                           CASE WHEN @OrderByAndOrder = 'colum1 desc' THEN u.Colum1 END DESC
                                  FOR JSON PATH, INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES
                                  )
                              FROM Table2 t2
                              WHERE t2.Table1Id = s.Id
                                AND
                              --Search by (;) colum1
                                (
                                        (ISJSON(@Filter) IS NULL) OR
                                        (JSON_VALUE(@Filter, '$.Colum1') = N'') OR
                                        (JSON_VALUE(@Filter, '$.Colum1') IS NULL) OR
                                        ((ISJSON(@Filter) IS NOT NULL) AND
                                            (JSON_VALUE(@Filter, '$.Colum1') <> N'') AND
                                                EXISTS( SELECT * FROM STRING_SPLIT(JSON_VALUE(@Filter, '$.Filter'), ';')
                                                        WHERE t2.[Colum1] LIKE CONCAT('%', [Value], '%')
                                                        AND [value] <> ''
                                                    )
                                            )
                                    ) )
                                ORDER BY
                                CASE WHEN @OrderByAndOrder = 'Colum1 asc' then t2.[Target] END ASC,
                                CASE WHEN @OrderByAndOrder = 'Colum1 desc' then t2.[Target] END DESC,
                                FOR JSON PATH, INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES
                          )
FROM Table1 (NOLOCK) mainTable
INNER JOIN Table2 t2
 ON mainTable.Id = t2.Table1Id
WHERE
mainTable.Id IN (SELECT Id FROM #Ids) --Could potentially join
AND
...
--same JSON filters on columns in mainTable

--Doing some more stuff with cte
```

Populating `Object1` and `Object2` within `Object1` is causing significant load on this procedure. Is there anything I can do to improve the performance and keep the objects as is?

Comment: No suggestion at all?

Comment: do you have sample data? or could you post a whole proc with some data so we can play around and troubleshoot it, But your main issue is that you are running a select inside the select which is known for bad performance what you could is use OUTER APPLY

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot post my data online nor I can put the whole proc. I do know my issue is caused by those selects. What I'm looking for is an alternate solution for it.

Comment: in that case, I would suggest looking into this https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6037/sql-server-uncorrelated-and-correlated-subquery/ , which can provide a better view of why you having an issue with a correlated subquery, try switching the query for the  cross apply(inner join) or outer apply(left join) depending what you need.

Comment: Have you been clearing the query plan cache prior to testing. You could also omit the @OrderByAndOrder bits and see if there is any performance related changes. When troubleshooting issues like this, it often helps to remove all parameters and narrow down to the smallest level of granularity that reproduces the problem. Clearing the query plan just removes the possibility of a bad plan being cached.

Comment: I'm really not sure what you're expecting from a bounty here. It's effectively impossible for us to test, and improve your SQL when you won't provide us the full statement, or provide us with sample data. With no query plan either, there's nothing we can actually do here.

Comment: The bounty was set just to get some attention to the question. I understand I'm making this harder for all of you by not providing the full proc and test data, but all I'm looking for is an alternate solution (some type of join) that could accomplish the same result. That was I can do some internal testing.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it will do the trick, but you should try to add OPTION (RECOMPILE) at the end of you query.